# UPDATE: Calculate vector length according to str value in specific column in Python

Tags: python, vector, counter

I am trying to measure the length of vectors based on a value of the first column of my input data.
For instance: my input data is as follows:

```
dog nmod+n+-n   4
dog nmod+n+n-a-commitment-n 6
child   into+ns-j+vn-pass-rb-divide-v   3
child   nmod+n+ns-commitment-n  5
child   nmod+n+n-pledge-n   3
hello   nmod+n+ns   2
```

The value that I want to calculate is based on an identical value in the first column. For instance, I would calculate a value based on all rows in which `dog` is in the first column, then I would calculate a value based on all rows in which `child` is in the first column... and so on.

I have worked out the mathematics to calculate the vector length (Euc. norm). However, I am unsure how to base the calculation based on grouping the identical values in the first column.

So far, this is the code that I have written:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import getopt
import datetime
import math

print "starting:",
print datetime.datetime.now()


def countVectorLength(infile, outfile):

    with open(infile, 'rb') as inputfile:
        flem, _, fw = next(inputfile).split()
        current_lem = flem
        weights = [float(fw)]
        for line in inputfile:
            lem, _, w = line.split() 
            if lem == current_lem:
                weights.append(float(w))
            else:
                print current_lem,
                print math.sqrt(sum([math.pow(weight,2) for weight in weights]))

                current_lem = lem
                weights = [float(w)]

        print current_lem,
        print math.sqrt(sum([math.pow(weight,2) for weight in weights]))

            print "Finish:",
            print datetime.datetime.now()

path = '/Path/to/Input/'
pathout = '/Path/to/Output'
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    outfile = 'output' + infile
    print "current file is:" + infile

    countVectorLength(path + infile, pathout + outfile)
```

This code outputs the length of vector of each individual lemma. The above data gives me the following output:

```
dog 7.211102550927978
child   6.48074069840786
hello   2
```

**UPDATE**
I have been working on it and I have managed to get the following working code, as updated in the code sample above. However, as you will be able to see. The code has a problem with the output of the very last line of each file --- which I have solved rather rudimentarily by manually adding it. However, because of this problem, it does not permit a clean iteration through the directory -- outputting all of the results of all files in an appended `>` document. Is there a way to make this a bit cleaner, pythonic way to output directly each individual corresponding file in the outpath directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you need to transform the input into something like

```
dog => [4,2]
child => [3,5,3]
etc
```

It goes like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
for line in file:
    line = line.split('\t')
    data[line[0]].append(line[2])
```

Once this is done, the rest is obvious:

```
def vector_len(vec):
   you already got that

vector_lens = {name: vector_len(values) for name, values in data.items()}
```

Comment: This gives a traceback error: 
`TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable` -- see updated code

Comment: @owwoow14: what I posted is not working code - I intentionally left out some details which you should be able to figure out yourself.